# Uniqueness of PDE Solution using Energy Method

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have the PDE given by

\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial C}{\partial t}-\nabla\cdot(D\nabla C)+V\cdot\nabla C+RC&=\sum_{i=1}^{N}w_{i}(t)\delta(x-x_{i})\\
C(x,0)&=C_{0}(x)\\
C(0,t)&=C(t)\\
\nabla C(\ell,t)&=0
\end{align}
I would like to show the uniqueness of the solututions using the energy methods. I read a book by Evans ([page 63](https://books.google.co.ke/books?id=Xnu0o_EJrCQC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)) where they showed uniqueness to the Heat equation. The problem is I dont know how to come up with the energy function inorder to use for the problem.